# Error converting numeric values into words - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Iam trying to convert numeric values into words. I done it successfully up to seven numeric values like: 1069000. by using the following sql:

```
**UPPER(TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ((1069000), 'j'), 'jsp'))in_words**
```

But when i increase one more zero like:10690000  it gives me the following error:

**date format picture ends before converting entire input string**

Please anyone help to convert numeric values into words having more than eight characters like **10690000**

Thanks in advance

Comment: for example, "TEN MILLION FIVE THOUSANDS SIX HUNDREDS ONLY" like this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have got the solution, Thanks to all. Please view the solution below.



 SELECT upper(case
                   when length(floor(instr_amount)) > 12 then
                    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(floor(floor(instr_amount) / 1000000000000), 'j'),
                            'jsp') || ' TRILLION ' ||
                    DECODE(substr(floor(instr_amount), length(floor(instr_amount)) - 11, 3),
                           0,
                           '',
                           (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(to_number(substr(floor(instr_amount),
                                                             length(floor(instr_amount)) - 11,
                                                             3)),
                                            'J'),
                                    'JSP')) || ' BILLION ') ||
                    DECODE(substr(floor(instr_amount), length(floor(instr_amount)) - 8, 3),
                           0,
                           '',
                           (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(to_number(substr(floor(instr_amount),
                                                             length(floor(instr_amount)) - 8,
                                                             3)),
                                            'J'),
                                    'JSP')) || ' MILLION ') ||
                    DECODE(substr(floor(instr_amount), length(floor(instr_amount)) - 5),
                           0,
                           '',
                           (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(substr(floor(instr_amount),
                                                   length(floor(instr_amount)) - 5),
                                            'J'),
                                    'JSP'))) ||
                    decode((instr_amount - floor(instr_amount)) * 100,
                           0,
                           '',
                           ' AND ' ||
                           TO_CHAR(TO_DATE((instr_amount - floor(instr_amount)) * 100, 'j'),
                                   'jsp') || ' CENTS')
                   when length(floor(instr_amount)) > 9 then
                    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(floor(floor(instr_amount) / 1000000000), 'j'), 'jsp') ||
                    ' BILLION ' ||
                    DECODE(substr(floor(instr_amount), length(floor(instr_amount)) - 8, 3),
                           0,
                           '',
                           (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(to_number(substr(floor(instr_amount),
                                                             length(floor(instr_amount)) - 8,
                                                             3)),
                                            'J'),
                                    'JSP')) || ' MILLION ') ||
                    DECODE(substr(floor(instr_amount), length(floor(instr_amount)) - 5),
                           0,
                           '',
                           (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(substr(floor(instr_amount),
                                                   length(floor(instr_amount)) - 5),
                                            'J'),
                                    'JSP'))) ||
                    decode((instr_amount - floor(instr_amount)) * 100,
                           0,
                           '',
                           ' AND ' ||
                           TO_CHAR(TO_DATE((instr_amount - floor(instr_amount)) * 100, 'j'),
                                   'jsp') || ' CENTS')
                   when length(floor(instr_amount)) > 7 then
                    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(floor(floor(instr_amount) / 1000000), 'j'), 'jsp') ||
                    ' MILLION ' ||
                    DECODE(substr(floor(instr_amount), length(floor(instr_amount)) - 5),
                           0,
                           '',
                           (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(substr(floor(instr_amount),
                                                   length(floor(instr_amount)) - 5),
                                            'J'),
                                    'JSP'))) ||
                    decode((instr_amount - floor(instr_amount)) * 100,
                           0,
                           '',
                           ' AND ' ||
                           TO_CHAR(TO_DATE((instr_amount - floor(instr_amount)) * 100, 'j'),
                                   'jsp') || ' CENTS')
                   else
                    decode((floor(instr_amount)),
                           0,
                           '',
                           ((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE((floor(instr_amount)), 'J'), 'JSP')))) ||
                    decode((instr_amount - floor(instr_amount)) * 100,
                           0,
                           '',
                           ' AND ' ||
                           TO_CHAR(TO_DATE((instr_amount - floor(instr_amount)) * 100, 'j'),
                                   'jsp') || ' CENTS')
                 end) in_words FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has some limitations: for spelling number greater than 7 numeric characters you should use your own function. Happily, Tom Kyte has already written it.

See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650

I duplicate code here due to site would be unavaliable or link would be deleted:

```
create or replace
function spell_number( p_number in number )
return varchar2
  as
      type myArray is table of varchar2(255);
      l_str    myArray := myArray( '',
                             ' thousand ', ' million ',
                             ' billion ', ' trillion ',
                             ' quadrillion ', ' quintillion ',
                             ' sextillion ', ' septillion ',
                             ' octillion ', ' nonillion ',
                             ' decillion ', ' undecillion ',
                             ' duodecillion ' );

      l_num   varchar2(50) default trunc( p_number );
      l_return varchar2(4000);
  begin
      for i in 1 .. l_str.count
      loop
          exit when l_num is null;

          if ( substr(l_num, length(l_num)-2, 3) <> 0 )
          then
             l_return := to_char(
                             to_date(
                              substr(l_num, length(l_num)-2, 3),
                                'J' ),
                         'Jsp' ) || l_str(i) || l_return;
          end if;
          l_num := substr( l_num, 1, length(l_num)-3 );
      end loop;

      return l_return;
end;
/
```